# How to set nexus repository URL in SBT for sonatypeRelease?

Tags: maven, sbt, sbt-release

I am trying to make my jar available in maven central .All works fine when I do it manually  from nexus repository manager UI. Problem occurs when I try to automate the complete steps using `sbt-release` plugin .On running `sonatypeRelease` I see it tries to connect to `Nexus repository URL: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local`  and later failed to connect throwing below error
`No credential is found for oss.sonatype.org. Prepare ~/.sbt/(sbt_version)/sonatype.sbt file` .
In my `sonatype.sbt` URL I have set below config

```
credentials += Credentials(
    "Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager",
    "s01.oss.sonatype.org",
    "username",
    "password"

)
```

I am not sure how can I make  `sonatypeRelease` take the config url instead of default one .I am quite sure this `sonatype.sbt` is being referenced as publishrelease works and it takes the correct sonatype nexus repository URL.
Any help on this would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed putting these lines in my build.sbt file

```
sonatypeCredentialHost := "s01.oss.sonatype.org"
sonatypeRepository := "https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local"
```